# c# combinations with linq

Tags: c#, linq, combinations

I have an array of values, e.g. { 0, 1, 2 } which can be in one of two states { 0, 1 }.

Is there a simple way (perhaps using a linq query) to get a list of all combinations of { value, state } (where value is unique) so that I get results like:

```
{
{ { 0, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 2, 0 } },
{ { 0, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 2, 1 } },
{ { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 0 } },
{ { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 } },
{ { 0, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, { 2, 0 } },
{ { 0, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, { 2, 1 } },
{ { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 0 } },
{ { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 } },
}
```

The "value" array can be of varying size, but they can only ever be in one of two states.

(It's not a cartesian product exactly, and I'm not sure what term can be used to describe it, so don't know what to google).

Thanks!

Comment: That's not permutations, that is combinations. Permutations would for example be turning 123 into {123,132,213,231,312,321}.

Comment: It's not even combinations. It's a cartesian product in disguise :-).

Comment: Well, I changed permutation to combination anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Cartesian product of Cartesian products:

```
var groups = from x in 
                (from v in values
                 from s in states
                 select new {v,s})
             group x by x.v into gx
             select gx;

var perms = from a in groups[0]
            from b in groups[1]
            from c in groups[2]
            select new {a,b,c};
```

The groups query produces a Lookup (conceptually a read-only Dictionary of IEnumerables) containing the simple Cartesian product of all values and states (6 elements), grouped by their value. Then, the second query produces a Cartesian product of the elements of the Cartesian product taken three at a time, one from each group in the Lookup.

To make this work with an unknown number of dimensions would be tricky; if you don't absolutely have to make it work that way I would avoid it. I think the most elegant way would be to define a set of extension methods for the System.Tuple generic classes:

```
public static Tuple<T1,T2> Append(this Tuple<T1> tuple, T2 addend)
{
   return Tuple.Create(tuple.Item1, addend);
}

public static Tuple<T1,T2, T3> Append(this Tuple<T1,T2> tuple, T3 addend)
{
   return Tuple.Create(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2, addend);
}

...
```

Then, you can take these helpers and use them in a looped version of the second query:

var perms = from a in groups[0]
            select Tuple.Create(a);

foreach(var group in groups.Skip(1))
    perms = from a in perms
            from b in group
            select a.Append(b);

This will produce an enumerable of Tuples of the required length, containing the elements of the anonymous type produced in the first query (which can be refactored to produce strongly-typed 2-item Tuples if you wish). You may have an issue with using the perms collection variable to refer to collections of ever-growing Tuples; this is the tricky part.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused by this answer. I think it needs to be "group x by" in the groups query? Also how does gx get to the second query? The fact that you're using indices 0 1 2 explicitly makes me think that this won't handle varying values array sizes? (Sorry, I'm pretty new to linq, so might be missing something obvious).

Comment: True on all counts; I updated the group by clause and the references to the grouped data. To make this work with an unknown number of dimensions would be tricky, but possible; basically you would loop through a query that took the result of the previous query and Cartesian-joined the next dimension to each result. The trick would be flattening that structure back out from these nested arrays or anonymous types back into a one-dimensional collection of tuples.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I had to use .ToArray() in order to be able to index the groups variable. I'll have a go at varying the dimensions and see what I can come up with.

Comment: a tip for writing queries that can be read more easily: "from x in (SUBQUERY) TAIL" can also be written "SUBQUERY into x TAIL". So your query could be "from v in values from s in states select new {v,s} into x group x by x.v into gx select gx". The benefit of that syntax is that it is easier to read top-to-bottom; you don't end up introducing a range variable x that is then not used until much later. This "query continuation" syntax puts the range variable introductions close to their usages.

Comment: As a last note, I got this working for variable dimensions by using the code from [here](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2010/08/01/linq-cartesian-3). After creating the lookup groups, I can just call 'var cornerCoords = CartesianProduct(groups.ToArray());'

Answer (score 2):

try

```
var values = new int[]{0,1,2};
var states = new int[]{0,1};

var permutations = from v in values
                   from s in states
                   select new {v,s}
```

you simply need a cross product of two arrays regardless of size of arrays

Comment: No, what's being asked for isn't a cross-product. Your code will produce 6 pairs, whereas what's wanted is 8 triples of pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
var lst1 = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2 };
var lst2 = new List<int> { 0, 1 };

lst1.ForEach(i => {
    Console.WriteLine("{");
    lst2.ForEach(j => Console.Write("{ " + i + "," + j + "}"));
    Console.WriteLine("}");
});
```

This won't really be in the format you want; you should build some kind of array(s) and then join it on "," and/or "}, {". This should give you the general idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

As the two states can be seen as bits, you can get the combinations by simply counting and converting the bits to items in an array:

```
int maxValue = 2;
int[][][] values = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << maxValue).Select(n =>
  Enumerable.Range(0, maxValue + 1).Select(m =>
    new[] { m, (n >> (maxValue - m)) & 1 }
  ).ToArray()
).ToArray();
```